# Measuring the effect of multiple time-dependent interventions

Tags: regression, logistic, panel-data

I was asked to analyze the effect of multiple interventions on a self-reported indicator (5-point Likert-scale).
Essentially, there are 23 individuals who went through 5 "interventions", and after each intervention, they answered some question on a five-point Likert-scale.
I want to know whether the interventions changed participants' answers over time.

My initial thought was to use a mixed effects ordered logistic panel regression using individual-level random effects, with 1 DV (5 point Likert-scale questions) and each intervention as a fixed-effects explanatory variable.

In Stata, that would look something like this:

`meologit DV i.session || id:, vce(cluster id)`

My first question is: does that make sense?

My second question is: I think I would like the **additional** effect of each intervention. I know that I can just change the reference point for `i.session`, but I obviously do not want 4 regression tables.
Is there another way to capture the effect of each additional intervention, using the prior session as the new baseline?

Thanks!

Comment: Was this a randomized cross-over study with the interventions given in different order in different randomized groups? There is a substantial literature on randomized cross-over trials that may help you. Is it assumed that from one treatment period to the next the effects from previous interventions have gone away? Are people in a stable condition (i.e. you don't expect a substantial time-trend over the study period)?

Comment: It's the same group, with essentially the "same" intervention several times in a row. Basically, it's some sort of mediation/moderation session about the same topic. The idea is to look for changes in self-reported attitudes, and e.g. if sessions 4 or 5 had any additional impact. Thus, there is no cross-sectional variation, it's basically only a within-subject "design". 
(Obviously, anything at that point has to be taken with a grain of salt)

Comment: Is there a randomized control group that didn't get sessions (or less ideal: historical controls showing what happens in this exact situation without sessions)? Otherwise, it's hard to say anything about whether the sessions had an effect, because there might also just some natural fluctuations in responses (or some effect of being as repeatedly) or long-term trends, which only gets worse, if people were initially included based on reporting e.g. "bad values" (which tends to induce regression to the mean). It's usually not the case that nothing would change in the absence of an intervention.

Comment: Sadly, there is no randomized control group, and there is not even a survey prior to the first intervention. Yeah it is hard to say anything with confidence. Afaik, these mediation/discussion sessions were all about 1 (pretty obscure) topic, with a rather specific goal of the organizers to make people more "pro-social". Given how narrow the topic is, I'd assume that participants wouldn't have changed their minds without the intervention, but of course they might just feel differently on different days. My question is, were we to assume no changes in trends, would such a regression make sense?

Comment: Sure, if you were 100% sure that no change would occur, if you repeatedly asked people about pro-social attitudes and that the answers to these questions never vary over time, then this sounds like it would do something reasonable (you could of course debate assuming more sophisticated correlation structure over time, but otherwise). By the way, I assume you also have an assessment prior to the first session, against which to judge the first session.